# How to authenticate a LocalPlayer for Gamecenter

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to authenticate a LocalPLayer but I get errors and I can't figure out how to fix them. I am getting this off the Apple Developers forums and it has errors.

1. "no visible @interface for ViewController2 declares the selector disable gamcenter"
2. No visible @interface for 'ViewController2' declares the selector 
   'showAuthenticationDialogWhenReasonable:'
3. No visible @interface for 'ViewController2' declares the selector 'authenticatedPlayer:'

   ```
    - (void) authenticateLocalPlayer
       {
       GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
   localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
    if (viewController != nil)
    {

        [self showAuthenticationDialogWhenReasonable: viewController];
    }
    else if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated)
    {

        [self authenticatedPlayer: localPlayer];
    }
    else
    {
        [self disableGameCenter];
    }
   }];
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've written in your question was lifted directly from Apple's documentation (specifically the ["Authenticating A Local Player"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH8-SW19) section).

As the comment in that code says:

> showAuthenticationDialogWhenReasonable: is an example method name. 
>   Create your own method that displays an authentication view when
>   appropriate for your app.

and

> authenticatedPlayer: is an example method name. Create your own method
>   that is called after the loacal player is authenticated.

and

"`disableGameCenter`" is the same.

All of them refer to "`self`", which means your code is looking for those implementations within the ViewController2 object.